# Stopping maven from running test while compiling intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, build

I am having a problem regarding my code keeps on running test while compiling the code but the unit test is wrong and I am trying to debug it but I can't. Where to look for the wrong configuration? I have search the whole internet for it but maybe my keyword is wrong.

TLDR: My code cannot compile because my current Unit Test is failed, I cannot debug the unit test because I can't build my project.

Comment: whan is the error that you get once you do mvn clean install ? you need to have compiled code in order to debug unit testing .

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi: If I run that command in the terminal => error because some dependencies are hosted in a private hosting.
If I run that command using Maven tab in IntelliJ
=> 1st case: The wrong test is there -> Can't compile
=> 2nd case: The wrong test is not there -> a normal mvn clean install happen

Comment: You need to correct testcase as you need to have code compiled wheather it is private hosting or public

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi: How can I correct it if I can't debug it man? The whole purpose of this ticket is to be able to debug the wrong test man

Comment: If you open the main method file in the IDEA and use the gutter to run it, it won't run the test and when compiling and you should debug any code you need. If you are running some Maven goals to compile, you need to use some flags to skip tests.

Comment: @LJ replica: Could you tell me more about "using the gutter to run" part? I don't really get it.

Comment: Check the guide here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html#quick-way The IDEA will show a run button in the gutter for the main method so you can click the run button to run/debug it. In this case, it only compiles the needed code and runs it which won't run tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for anyone who stumbles upon the same problem.
In IntelliJ Idea > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner > **UN-TICK** Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a skip tests configuration in your maven plugin in `pom.xml`. for example :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then when you rerun the project, the unit tests will not run.
Or you just can compile your project in another way in the command line.

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

This command will nether compile the unit test code ,nor run the unit test.

Comment: appreciated man, it helps me solve the building part but still I can't debug it because the test is failed

Comment: mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true won't run testcase .

Answer (score 0):

Try With Install Maven Extension and Turn off Test `Toggle skip Tests` Mode.